# Manipulate a web-page control with VBA

Tags: vba, video, web

Thanks in advance for your answers.

I have a little Excel document that is made so that the naïve user can enter web pages in an Excel sheet, hit a button, and play the videos from that page in their browser, in full screen, and automatically loop the videos without any further user interaction.  It basically creates a slide show of videos.

I originally made it for YouTube and it works fine there.  I'm now trying to expand it to use another site.  It works as planned but needs an extra step.

Whereas YouTube was made with a Full Screen mode that I can access programatically, this website has embedded videos.  (An example: https://www.sharecare.com/video/health-topics-a-z/copd/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-my-copd-from-getting-worse).

You can see in the code that I open IE in full screen mode (which it does) but that's the full web page (header, side banner etc.).  I want the video from that page to be the only element, full screen.

If I physically go into the page I can select for the video to play full screen.  I've tried searching for various ways to do this, but most of the posts are for something else or how to get a video to play inside Excel rather than what I'm doing.

```
Sub StartLooping()

Dim IEapp As Object
Dim VidAddr1, VidAddr2 As String
Dim AddrStrStart, AddrStrEnd As Long
Dim AddrFudge1, AddrFudge2 As Integer
Dim TimeStart, DurMin, DurSec, DurTot As Single
Dim LRAll, LRVid, LRMin, LRSec, LRVidB, LRMinB, LRSecB As Integer
Dim I As Integer

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
On Error GoTo ErrorHandle


'Review Sheet
LRVid = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
LRMin = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
LRSec = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
LRVidB = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
LRMinB = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
LRSecB = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
LRAll = Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row

If LRVid <> LRMin Then
    MsgBox "You have to include video address and how long (the minutes and the seconds - use 0 if needed)"
    Exit Sub
End If

If LRVid <> LRSec Then
    MsgBox "You have to include video address and how long (the minutes and the seconds - use 0 if needed)"
    Exit Sub
End If

If LRVidB <> LRMinB Then
    MsgBox "You have to include video address and how long (the minutes and the seconds - use 0 if needed)"
    Exit Sub
End If

If LRVidB <> LRSecB Then
    MsgBox "You have to include video address and how long (the minutes and the seconds - use 0 if needed)"
    Exit Sub
End If


'Start of For-Next Loop

For I = 20 To LRAll

'Set Addr

'VidAddr1
If Len(Range("S" & I).Text) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
        VidAddr1 = Range("S" & I).Text
End If

VidAddr2 = VidAddr1

'Set Timer
TimeStart = Timer 'Start time
DurMin = Range("T" & I).Value
DurSec = Range("U" & I).Value
DurTot = (DurMin * 60) + DurSec


'Open the web page
Set IEapp = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application") 'Set IEapp = InternetExplorer

    With IEapp
        .Silent = True 'No Pop-ups
        .Visible = True
        .FullScreen = True
        .Navigate VidAddr2 'Load web page

        'Keep it open for the duration
            Do While Timer < (TimeStart + DurTot)

                'Check for Esc - refers to a public function
                If KeyDown(vbKeyEscape) Then
                    IEapp.Quit
                    Set IEapp = Nothing
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            Loop

        'Close the page
            IEapp.Quit
            Set IEapp = Nothing

    End With

    If I = LRAll Then I = 19

Next I

ErrorHandle:

    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I copied the code.  It works fine.  It's just that extra bit of "Oh, I did that, here's how to go about it" that I need.

The browser used is IE so I can keep it simple, but if this were possible in another common browser that would be good to know.

Here's the second set that I tried today (9/12)

```
Dim IEapp As Object
Dim IEAppColl As HTMLButtonElement

'Open doc
Set IEapp = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application") 'Set IEapp =    InternetExplorer

    With IEapp
        .Silent = True 'No Pop-ups
        .Visible = True
        '.FullScreen = True
        .navigate "https://www.sharecare.com/video/health-topics-a-z/copd/got-copd-ask-your-doctor-about-vitamin-d"

        Do While .readyState < 4 Or .Busy
        Loop

        Set IEAppColl = IEapp.Document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")
        If IEAppColl.Name = "Fullscreen" Then
              IEAppColl.Click
        End If

    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

For the example COPD page given this works with Selenium basic. You install from [here](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) and then go `VBE > Tools > References >` and add a reference to `Selenium Type Library`. You can also use an `IEDriver` to work with InternetExplorer rather than Chrome (which uses `ChromeDriver`).

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PlayFullScreen()
    Dim d As WebDriver, t As Date, ele As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.sharecare.com/video/health-topics-a-z/copd/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-my-copd-from-getting-worse"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .FindElementByCss("[title='Accept Cookies']")
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        If Not ele Is Nothing Then ele.Click
        .FindElementByCss("#myExperience").Click
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        .FindElementByCss("[Title=Fullscreen]", timeout:=7000).Click

        Stop                                     '<==Delete me later      
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  Selenium may be a long-term solution.  I'm in a corporate environment so I have to get permissions that will take past the due date.  The code is helpful, and I'll have to explore it more tomorrow.

Comment: When it comes to browser automation it is a more robust method in my opinion so worth it in the long run.

Comment: I took those elements and tried to emulate them, but keep running into a runtime error (Type mismatch).  Tried a bunch of different ways to Dim that variable.

Comment: @ARB What do you mean by took and tried to emulate? As in re-write for Internet Explorer? It is possible but I am not sure you will get the screen maximize part to work. You could try studying the events on the page to see if there is a particular combo that succeeds but it in my general tests selenium had no problem completing the tasks whereas IE, without selenium, failed on that part.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean: tried to reproduce in IE.  Seems so close, but keep getting that error.

Comment: Want to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) your current code and indicate the line producing the error? It might be possible but I don't think the enlarge bit is a matter of selecting the right element as that is easy. The problem is mimicking the right events to enable the enlarge (I think)/ perhaps needing to attach an event.....

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to, instead of using a *browser* to play video, use a **video player**.

Under "More Controls" you should have a "Windows Media Player", and likely others, depending on what you have installed.

[image]

For example, I've used the [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) control on Access forms. When you install VLC it automatically adds the control to Office (so I assume Office has to be installed *first*.)

---

Here's a **tutorial** I found online:

- Link: **[How to Play Video on Access Form](http://www.iaccessworld.com/play-video-access-form/)**

[image: img]

---

### Random Tip Time:

- It can be tricky to Google *about* a website because, for example, using the search term `*YouTube*` in a Google search results in a list of YouTube *content* (videos).

  Exclude results from a specific site with Google's `site:` and `-` operators like:

  [`"microsoft access" form play youtube video  -site:youtube.com`](https://google.com/search?q=%22microsoft%20access%22%20form%20play%20youtube%20video%20%20-site%3Ayoutube.com)

  ...which is how I found the tutorial above, and several others.
- Using the search term `access` can also be tricky to search for since it's such a common word, which is why I'll often enclose it in quotes like "MS Access" or "Microsoft Access" (like above), which makes Google search for those words *in that order*.

  <sub>[(More Google tips)](https://zapier.com/blog/advanced-google-search-tricks/#operators)</sub>

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.  That "-site" thing will come in handy.  If I have the video (YouTube for example) everything works.  It's on other pages that I don't have the video (or else I could embed in an Access form, Excel sheet etc.  I can find the video ID but don't know enough of this territory to know how to 1) access what's playing that video and 2) add a full screen attribute, as if I clicked the full screen in the embedded player.

Comment: ARB - I'm glad it's helpful. I'm not clear on whether you said you **so** know where to find the URL's?  On most sites, viewing the page source will give clues, even for sites that want to keep them hidden. (Don't break any rules, but experimenting for "testing purposes" is alright. :-) For example, I slapped together an Excel sheet for a friend so he can put in any Tumblr username, and Excel will go download all of the videos associated to the account, one by one.  (again, for testing purposes.)

Comment: It's that I wanted to automate.  I myself can inspect the elements, find the URLs for the videos and use them  (which is pretty the temporary solution I ended up with).  But I wanted to give a product off to the user where s/he wouldn't have to get the URLs.  Also, while I think displaying videos that people put out publicly is generally fair, I didn't want to take them down to a local machine.

Comment: @ARB - (psst - I don't actually care what you do...!)  But so you're aware, major corporations usually have website terms saying you have to use their stuff only on their sites, the way they want to present it (ie,not in an ad-free desktop Access app etc etc blah blah). Just because something's available online, doesn't mean you're *allowed* to do what you want with it. In your case "for promotional purposes" may be allowable depending on the video source. Again I don't care - and also disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer!

Comment: @ARB - ...Another thing to keep in mind is [so] doesn't like to host instructions on breaking other company's terms.  Hence, when in doubt, be vague.  "Test away!"  Some people insist on doing things by the book (like your boss might if you have one) in which case you just need to do some research. For example, YouTube T&C allows for `distribution through functionality offered by the Service (such as the Embeddable Player)`... which you could place in an Access/Excel Web Browser control and be all legal. Anyhow, just a friendly heads up. (Did i mention that I don't care?)  ‎